# Typescript: Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a code:

```
// Library interfaces
interface PersonalData {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    nick: string;
    friends?: Friends[];
}

interface Friends extends PersonalData { }

// I want to add new props girls in friend interface
interface NewPropGirl {
    girl: string;
    friends?: NewPops[];
}

interface NewPops extends NewPropGirl { }

const test = (): Friends[] & NewPops[]  => {
    return [{
        name: 'Oleg',
        age: 25,
        nick: 'yyy',
        girl: 'Test',
        friends: [{
            name: 'Roman',
            age: 22,
            nick: 'bob',
            girl: 'Test',
        }]
    }];
}
```

I want to add a new interface parameter **girl** to the library interface. In this code, I have an Error on line 31

TYPESCRIPT VERSION 3.5.3

```
Type '{ name: string; age: number; nick: string; girl: string; friends: { girl: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Friends[] & NewPops[]'.
  Type '{ name: string; age: number; nick: string; girl: string; friends: { girl: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Friends[]'.
    Type '{ name: string; age: number; nick: string; girl: string; friends: { girl: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Friends'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'girl' does not exist in type 'Friends'.
```

Playground link: [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1#code/FDD0oAgGQSwIwE4EMEE8IAcEHsMGdgYA7AFwFMEAzJAYzIgAUK9sikAbAESRKQgG9gEYRDYBbMgC4IeEgmIBzANxCRSBVNEBXMXAoqRomDQDW02fKLLVwyvLJEAJngD80gGL2neANoBdFQBfEGJyKlp6TxgHZwgyAA9yb0ZmVg5uXgEIYLBIAEkIAHckUggSbAgkR0dRMkLMHHxCUgpqOggAOTqGRoBxGAR2ARsIBQH2czlFAxE7aO83Tu7cXwDgHNDWiKXChhW4xJi8HZ7cfsGsnJpWWTKyW4BeCAAKAEoPL2d-CAAyE5XvhAHgA%20YaGBBkEhaBBECA%20QSGQziTQAcgA8uwyAoUQAaEaGdSaABMAFY8YiRERjGYICjUPTcfiRGNBtIUQAVe4kRkU2yfPDSeFMinItkAJWwYhKPN5BI00iJRPJssp1LZcGwcBlKtG4zZnNk2sRgT8IxNQSAA)

Comment: `NewPropGirl` should be derived from `PersonelData`. Or you have to mark all none existing properties on `PersonalData` as optional.

Comment: @Eldar I can't  mark all none existing properties on PersonalData as optional because it is interface from node_modules

Comment: Woah am a bit confused, but let me ask you something, you are putting cyclic dependency of interfaces, so from what i understand is your `friends?` variable could either be a `PersonalData` or `NewPropGirl` correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extended PersonalData to NewPropGirl to let your result hold an extra field and made that as the return type

```
interface PersonalData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  nick: string;
  friends ? : Friends[];
}

interface Friends extends PersonalData {}

// I want to add new props
interface NewPropGirl extends PersonalData {
  girl: string;
  friends ? : NewPops[];
}

interface NewPops extends NewPropGirl {}

const test = (): NewPops[] => {
  return [{
    name: 'Oleg',
    age: 25,
    nick: 'yyy',
    girl: 'Test',
    friends: [{
      name: 'Roman',
      age: 22,
      nick: 'bob',
      girl: 'Test',
    }]
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface PersonalData {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    nick: string;
    friends?: Friends[];
}

interface Friends extends PersonalData { }

// I want to add new props
interface NewPropGirl extends PersonalData {
    girl: string;
    friends?: NewPops[];
}

interface NewPops extends NewPropGirl { }

const test = (): Friends[] | NewPops[]  => {
    return [{
        name: 'Oleg',
        age: 25,
        nick: 'yyy',
        girl: 'Test',
        friends: [{
            name: 'Roman',
            age: 22,
            nick: 'bob',
            girl:"Bella"
        }]
    }];
}
```

See if it fit your needs. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1&ssl=34&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/FDD0oAgGQSwIwE4EMEE8IAcEHsMGdgYA7AFwFMEAzJAYzIgAUK9sikAbAESRKQgG9gEYRDYBbMgC4IeEgmIBzANxCRSBVNEBXMXAoqRomDQDW02fKLLVwyvLJEAJngD80gGL2neANoBdFQBfEGJyKlp6TxgHZwgyAA9yb0ZmVg5uXgEIYLBIAEkIAHckUggSbAgkR0dRMkLMHHxCUgpqOggAOTqGRoBxGAR2OMSYvBSEFjYuHj5BQwUB9nM5RQMRO2jvN07u3F8A4BzQ1oidwoY94aTYrvO+xaycmlZZMrJXgF4IAAoASg8vM5-BAAD5nC74YEQD4APgENggCDIJC0CCIEB8c0MInEmgA5AB5dhkBR4gA0CMM6k0ACYAKwU7E44xmCB41Ac8mUkQLQbSPEAFXeJC5TNsgLw0kx3KZuP5ACVsGISqKxVSNNIaTTGWrmaZ+XBsHBVbqILylgAiABCZHY7CQFpl2T8CMCB0CQA)